# убрать часть url при отобржаении картинки Laravel

Tags: laravel

сейчас у меня выводится как 
https://127.0.0.1:8080/admin/uploads/avatar/zM7kU6fquF.jpeg

а мне надо чтобы вывелось без admin
https://127.0.0.1:8080/uploads/avatar/zM7kU6fquF.jpeg

в роутах у меня так

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin', 'namespace'=>'Admin'], function (){
Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index');
Route::resource('/users', 'UsersController');
```

});

вот метод который дергает картинку

```
public function getImage()
{
    if($this->avatar == null)
    {
        return 'uploads/no-image.png';
    }

    return 'uploads/avatar/' . $this->avatar;
}
```

Вот так сохраняются файлы

```
public function uploadAvatar($image)
{
    if($image == null) { return; }
    $this->removeAvatar();

    $filename = str_random(10) . '.' . $image->extension();
    $image->storeAs('uploads/avatar/', $filename);
    $this->avatar = $filename;
    $this->save();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. Где хранятся файлы? 2. Как вставляете покажите

Comment: обновил пост выше

Comment: посмотрите конфиг filesystems.php